# Validating returned value in controller instead of doing in service

Tags: angularjs

I am having a method in my service as below.

```
module.service('Service', function($state, $rootScope) {

    var getRemoteItems = function(page, displayLimit) {
         var defferer = $q.defer()

        var query = new Parse.Query("Item");
        query.limit(displayLimit);
        query.skip(page * displayLimit);
        query.descending("createdAt");

        var items = [];

        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                //process results
                return results;
            },
            error: function(e) {
                return null;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Although it's working, I am trying to make changes so that in the controller which calls this method, can use success and failure checks instead of doing it in the service method.

I am not able to understand how to use promises in this example. I am expecting somehting like below.

```
Service.getRemotItems(1,10).then()...error()..
```

Please excuse me for any syntax issues in the example as I am new to Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already created the promise with `$q.defer()` you just need to resolve/reject it in the success & error callbacks

```
module.service('Service', function($state, $rootScope, $q) {

    var getRemoteItems = function(page, displayLimit) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var query = new Parse.Query("Item");
        query.limit(displayLimit);
        query.skip(page * displayLimit);
        query.descending("createdAt");

        var items = [];

        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                deferred.reject(e);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```